# How to fix @angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server' is not supported resolving ES modules after updating project from Angular 8 to Angular 15

Tags: angular

I followed the steps in https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.0-16.0 to update my angular app from Angular 8 to Angular 15. I did have to --force my way through the process, which I know is not recommended, but when I run `ng serve` I get the following error:

```
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Angular/IFAQUOTE/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/util/reportUnhandledError.js:13
            throw err;
            ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/Users/xxx/Desktop/Angular/IFAQUOTE/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /Users/xxx/Desktop/Angular/IFAQUOTE/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
Did you mean to import /Users/xxx/Desktop/Angular/IFAQUOTE/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:218:17)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:838:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1036:11)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:251:12)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:140:32)
    at DefaultModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:227:28)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1163:37)
    at importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:428:21)
    at importModuleDynamically (node:internal/vm:105:46) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
  url: 'file:///Users/xxx/Desktop/Angular/IFAQUOTE/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server'
}

Node.js v20.5.0
npm 9.8.0

Angular CLI: 16.1.8
Node: 20.5.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.8.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 15.2.9
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.1202.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular              12.2.13
@angular-devkit/core                       12.2.13
@angular-devkit/schematics                 16.1.8
@angular/cli                               16.1.8
@nguniversal/express-engine                v8.2.6
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   v8.2.6
@schematics/angular                        16.1.8
rxjs                                       6.5.5
typescript                                 4.9.5
zone.js                                    0.11.8
```

My package.json file looks like:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run ifaquote:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~15.2.9",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^8.1.0",
    "@commitlint/config-angular": "^8.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.9.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.1.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.4.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1406.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "echarts": "^4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.31",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "husky": "^3.0.0",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.31",
    "mat-table-exporter": "^15.0.0",
    "mobile-detect": "^1.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "n": "^9.1.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.3",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "ngx-echarts": "^4.2.1",
    "number-to-words": "^1.2.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.1.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~15.2.9",
    "@types/echarts": "^4.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.66",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I don't understand where exactly I've gone wrong, since all I did was follow the steps and run the code given, (and also removed "defaultProject" from angular.json since I saw it in a previous question as a potential solution).

Comment: next to your project, can you create a new angular 16 project and compare what you have in package.json, tsconfig.*.json files, etc.?  Seems like something to do with tsconfig options or an invalid version in package.json